# New csproj re-generates files forever when Visual Studio is open

Tags: c#, node.js, visual-studio, csproj

I'm generating some .cs files using `node.exe` before the compilation, which I then include in my project.

I call `node.exe` and define the steps for the generation via  CSProj. After migrating the CSProj to the new format `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` the files are constantly being generated, erased and generated again while Visual Studio is open (tested with VS2017 and VS2019).

This is my targets file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

   <Target Name="SetVariables">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_NodeJsExe Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\..\Node.js.redist\*\tools\win-x64\node.exe"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <__NodeJsExe>@(_NodeJsExe);</__NodeJsExe>
      <NodeJsExe>$(__NodeJsExe.Substring(0, $(__NodeJsExe.IndexOf(';'))))</NodeJsExe>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

   <Target Name="ProblemHere" BeforeTargets="TransformDuringBuild;PrepareForBuild;CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="SetVariables;CleanFilesBeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(NodeJsExe)&quot..." />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanFilesBeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Ts2LangFiles Include="$(GeneratedFolder)\**\*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(Ts2LangFiles)"/>
  </Target>
  </Project>
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that Visual Studio is building some targets at [design-time](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/master/docs/design-time-builds.md).

If I add this to my custom target, the files stop being constantly generated by MSBuild:

```
 <Target Name="ProblemHere" Condition="$(DesignTimeBuild) != true And $(BuildingProject) == true" BeforeTargets="TransformDuringBuild;PrepareForBuild;CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="SetVariables;CleanFilesBeforeBuild">
```

I just have yet to understand if this is a bug in Visual Studio or if the problem is mine and I'm using the targets like I'm not supposed to.